# Java generic function for performing calculations on integer, on double?

Tags: java, generics

Is this possible? Surely if you passed in a double, any sort of function implementation code which casts an object to an Integer would not be able to work unless the cast 'Integer' was specifically used? I have a function like:

```
public static void increment(Object o){
    Integer one = (Integer)o;
    system.out.println(one++);
}
```

I cant see how this could be made generic for a double? I tried

```
public static <E> void increment(E obj){
    E one = (E)obj;
    system.out.println(one++);
}
```

but it didn't like it?

Comment: You can't increment an `Integer` anyway.

Comment: You can with autoboxing/unboxing.

Comment: With enough [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) I could write a method such as `public static Number increment(Number n)` that could return the same subclass of Number that was passed in as the `n` parameter. Doing `public static Number add(Number n1, Number n2)` couldn't guarantee the actual return type though.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, method arguments are passed by value. Therefore, incrementing a method argument will not change the caller's value. So, you must either return the new value:

```
double increment(double x) {
    return x + 1;
}
```

or pass a reference type containing the value:

```
class MutableDouble {
    double value;
}

void increment(MutableDouble d) {
    d.value++;
}
```

In Java, type arguments must be of reference type, hence double is not a valid value for a type parameter. If you want primitive types, consider overloading the methods instead:

```
float increment(float f) {
    return f + 1;
}

double increment(double d) {
    return d + 1;
}
```

If you really want generics, you can do:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<N extends Number> N increment(N n) {
    if (n instanceof Double) {
        return (N) (Double) (((Double)n) + 1);
    } else if (n instanceof Float) {
        return (N) (Float) (((Float)n) + 1);
    } else if ( ...
        // handle remaining cases
    } else if (n == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected number type: " + n.getClass());
    }
}
```

This is godawful ugly though. What are you trying to accomplish by defining such a method? There's probably is an easier way ...

Answer (score 0):

What if you downcast it to a Double?

```
public static void increment(Object o) {
    Double d= (Double) o;
    System.out.println(d + 1.0);
}
```

**Update:** I tried this and it worked:

```
public static void increment(Object o) {
    Double d = Double.parseDouble(o.toString());
    System.out.println(d + 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Then it will fail if an `Integer` is passed as the argument.

Comment: As the guy above said, so does this mean you cannot make generic functions to actions which modify data, only present/sort data?

Comment: Well my second code works, no? Do you want it to return something? Stephen's comment is about the first snippet.

Comment: I'd like a function which can take an integer or double and increment :)

Comment: The second code does print the incremented value, but doesn't actually increment anything. As meriton  and Tom Hawtin point out, the `Integer`, `Double` etc. classes are immutable, so you have to return a new object with the incremented value.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read up on semantics that higher-level specialized languages have defined from cross-type arithmetic. A good example that I recommend is JSP EL specification.

It basically spells out how to implement such function...

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CEwQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fflaka.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2Fjsp-2_1-fr-spec-el.pdf&rct=j&q=jsp%20el%20specification&ei=erkwTZrZGJHogQfbxMWiCw&usg=AFQjCNH6oPO7WwgiHCBkST5vgsBxMZmWaQ&sig2=0hRqxe6G0brRGuzNOxEhGw&cad=rja

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double increment(double d)
{
  return d+1;
}
```

That will work for all primitive value types. Then all you have to do is cast the result ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to increment and get new value (not change immutable Integer instance), you can do something like this:

```
interface Arithmetics<T> {
    T inc(T val);
}

class IntegerArithmetics implements Arithmetics<Integer> {
    Integer inc(Integer val) { return val+1; }
}

//similarly DoubleArithmetics, BigIntegerArithmetics, ...
```

And call it to get your method:

```
public static <E> void increment(E obj, Arithmetics<E> arit){
    System.out.println(arit.inc(obj));
}
```

[Generic Java Math](http://code.google.com/p/generic-java-math/) library does exactly that for you.

Only thing is that you need to pass `Arithmetics` object around. If that is a big problem, you can initialize a `Map<Class,Arithmetics>`, and use `map.get(obj.getClass())` to get corresponding `Arithmetics`.